# Dynamically Created Div Misaligned

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a button on a form that dynamically adds inputs.
I used the tutorials on this site and with help was able to figure out how to basically align the div.  Now however, whenever I create a new line, my second and third inputs never seem to line up, when I put my form together.

Can someone help me either figure out why a duplication is not a true duplication or how to target the elements in the div.

CodePen http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/wzqABa

```
HTML:
  <div class="input-group" id="previousTeachingExperience">
                    <label id="teachingExpierience">Teaching Experience *</label>

                    <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="schoolBoard_1" placeholder="School Board" onblur="this.placeholder='Email'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" />
                    <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="position_1" placeholder="Position" onblur="this.placeholder='Position'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" />
                    <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="years_1" />
                    <input type="button" name="myButton" onclick="addJob()" value="+" />

CSS:

button
{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input[type="button"]
{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

input[type="button"]:focus
{
   outline: none;
}

label
{
    margin-left: 145px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    color: #859cad;
    text-align: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;

}

input.three-lines
{
    margin-left: 18px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c1cc;
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#left
{
    margin-left: 340px;
}

JS:

var i = 0;
function addJob()
{
    i++;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="left"><input type="text" class="three-lines" name="schoolBoard_'+i+'"><input type="text" class="three-lines" name="position_'+i+'"><input type="text" class="three-lines" name="years_'+i+'"></div>';

    document.getElementById("previousTeachingExperience").appendChild(div);
};
```

Comment: You have `#left {
    margin-left: 340px;
}`

Comment: For the overall div that's holding the inputs yes, to push it over to the left, but the classes on the inputs themselves should carry over no?

Comment: You have **spaces** between `<input>`s in top row (lol)

Comment: And there is no spaces betwen created ones.

Comment: Also, `margin-left: 340px` is very-very bad for small screen (try that)

Comment: Thanks Dimava, I was going a little batty! To compensate for where I need the inputs, what would you suggest for the margin left?

Comment: Put `<br>` after `<label>`

Comment: ids cannot be duplicated. There can only be unique id names per page. So change `#left` to `.left` and `<div id="left">` to `<div class="left">`